# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied when deploying to Plesk 12

Tags: asp.net, plesk

I just deployed my ASP.NET MVC5 (.net 4.6) application to my hosting using Publish option in Visual Studio and selecting FTP mode. Now when I try to browse to the app address it gives me the `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied` error. I'm using Plesk 12 in a shared hosting.

Please mind that it's a shared hosting and I'm using Plesk so don't come with the answer of changing IIS settings because I don't have access to that.

How do I fix it??

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and nothing was working for me. I fixed it by changing the .NET framework version to 4.5, instead of 4.5.2.

I wrote a [short article about it](http://blog.brendanlacanette.com/2015/07/systemcomponentmodelwin32exception.html) which shows you how to change the framework version and includes other solutions to try that might fix the error for your. Hopefully this helps!